# Why is the SUN_LEN macro dereferencing NULL without an error?

Tags: c, linux, testing

I'm currently looking at a clang sanitizer error that tells me that I'm dereferencing a nullptr during the runtime of my program. Looking at the source of the problem, I got to the `SUN_LEN` macro in `sys/un.h` on Arch Linux which looks like this:

```
/* Structure describing the address of an AF_LOCAL (aka AF_UNIX) socket.  */
struct sockaddr_un
  {
    __SOCKADDR_COMMON (sun_);
    char sun_path[108];     /* Path name.  */
  };


#ifdef __USE_MISC
# include <string.h>        /* For prototype of `strlen'.  */

/* Evaluate to actual length of the `sockaddr_un' structure.  */
//                                                      vvv This is NULL?
# define SUN_LEN(ptr) ((size_t) (((struct sockaddr_un *) 0)->sun_path)        \
              + strlen ((ptr)->sun_path))
#endif
```

It seems this macro is always trying to access NULL so the fault seems to be there. But I highly doubt this is a bug as this macro is used everywhere and seems to work fine (beside the sanitizer warning), so I'm wondering why this is not crashing and why it's there in the first place?

Comment: The macro is not accessing `NULL`, it just use that as the base address for pointer arithmetic with a `struct sockaddr_un`.

Comment: So the code tries to recreate `offsetof` of the field `sun_path`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The macro

```
#define SUN_LEN(ptr) ((size_t) (((struct sockaddr_un *) 0)->sun_path)        \
              + strlen ((ptr)->sun_path))
```

does not dereference a `NULL` pointer.

So let's take look at the internal parts of the macro:

```
(((struct sockaddr_un *) 0)->sun_path)
```

This is not deferencering, this is casting `NULL` pointer to a `struct sockaddr_un` pointer.
The `->sun_path` is there for the pointer arithmetic:

```
struct sockaddr_un *so = NULL;
char *offset = so->sun_path + strlen(ptr->sun_path);
```

The last part is the cast to `size_t`

```
size_t size = (size_t) offset;
```

which converts the address store in `offset` in a numerical `size_t` value.

In this case it is basically doing

```
size_t val = offsetof(struct sockaddr_un, sun_path) +
    strlen(ptr->sun_path) * sizeof *ptr->sun_path;
```

What I cannot tell you is why this macro is defined in that way, the guys
implementing this socket library might have good reasons for that instead of
using `offsetof`, which internal is also a macro. A `gcc -E` for this `offsetof`
shows me:

```
 size_t y = 
# 46 "a.c" 3 4
           __builtin_offsetof (
# 46 "a.c"
           struct sockaddr_un
# 46 "a.c" 3 4
           , 
# 46 "a.c"
           sun_path
# 46 "a.c" 3 4
           ) 
# 46 "a.c"
```